# Interesting explicit convergent subsequence for not converging bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, intuition, education

To illustrate the (power of) Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem I am searching for an example of a bounded but not convergent sequence and an explicit convergent subsequence.

I would like it to be non trivial in the sense that (cyclic) sequences like $(-1)^n$ or $1,2,3, 1,2,3, 1,2,3$ or $1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1$, where one can easily "see" the (constant) convergent subsequence don't count.

I wanted to use $\sin(n)$, but the construction of a convergent subsequence [isn't very explicit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803800/convergent-subsequence-for-sinn).

Comment: Consider maybe the decimal part of $en$, and note that the terms corresponding to $en!$ go to zero?

Comment: @Mindlack What an interesting example! How did you come up with it? I looked at the first few terms and believe you in saying that the subsequence converges to zero, but how can we show it?

Comment: This is a rather standard example, it seems (both the $n\alpha$ for irrational $\alpha$ and the $n!e$). To show the convergence of the subsequence, you can show that $\sum_{k=0}^n{k!^{-1}} \leq e \leq \sum_{k=0}^n{k!^{-1}}+\frac{1}{n}n!^{-1}$.

Comment: @Mindlack Which sequence do you mean by "$n \alpha$ for irrational $\alpha$"? Do we again consider the fractional part and only the $n!$-terms?

Comment: No, just consider the fractional part of $n\alpha$. There is a standard theorem saying the sequence is equidistributed in $[0,1]$. What’s interesting with $e$ is that we can find an explicit subsequence converging to $0$ (the $n!e$).

Comment: @Mindlack I would love if you could put this down as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try the sequence
$$ 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, \ldots $$
enumerating all rationals in $[0,1]$, which has all sorts of interesting convergent subsequences.

Comment: I guess the most interesting property is that it every real number from $[0,1]$ is a limit point of this sequence, and therefore its the only series I can think of with uncountable many subsequences.

Comment: Every infinite sequence has uncountably many subsequences (some of which may be equal).

Comment: You are right, I meant to say uncountably many **different convergent** subsequences.

Comment: Then, my statement holds, right?

Comment: Your statement "the only series I can think of ..."?  How do I know what you can think of?

Comment: Thats true, the statement I was referring to is that the sequence you proposed has  uncountably many different convergent subsequences.